# How would the air pressure inside the hyper loop affect the acceleration of the cabin?

Tags: acceleration, drag

I would like to ask a question about hyperloop's inner air pressure, how would air pressure inside the semi-vacuum tube affect the acceleration of the cabin? Is there any functions or equations to calculate such relationships?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Decrease in air pressure will decrease the density of air. For ideal gases this is shown by,

$D = \dfrac{MP}{RT}$, where M is the molar mass.

Now, drag is directly dependent on density of fluid, this is given [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_equation).